# SQL Server in Docker - admin port in use

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Recently, from out of the blue, whenever I start my docker-based SQL Server docker-compose file I have to wait 3 mins because SS cannot open the admin port (1434).

```
...
14:05:21.13 spid30s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
14:05:21.13 spid14s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
14:05:21.13 spid31s     Starting up database 'mydb'.
14:05:21.14 spid14s     The resource database build version is 15.00.4312. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
14:05:21.14 spid26s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
14:05:21.15 spid14s     [3]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
14:05:21.15 spid14s     Starting up database 'model'.
14:05:21.16 spid26s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
14:05:21.16 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
14:05:21.19 spid31s     Parallel redo is started for database ' mydb' with worker pool size [10].
14:05:21.23 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized.
14:05:21.25 spid14s     Clearing tempdb database.
14:05:21.32 spid30s     Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'mydb' with worker pool size [10].
14:05:21.35 spid14s     [2]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
14:05:21.35 spid14s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
14:05:21.71 spid14s     The tempdb database has 8 data file(s).
14:05:21.72 spid30s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
14:05:21.72 spid30s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
14:05:21.73 spid30s     Service Broker manager has started.
14:08:21.79 Server      Error: 26024, Severity: 16, State: 1.
14:08:21.79 Server      Server failed to listen on 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434. Error: 0x2742. To proceed, notify your system administrator.
14:08:21.79 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was not started because of error 0x2742, status code: 0x1. This error typically indicates a socket-based error, such as a port already in use.
14:08:21.79 spid26s     Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1431].
14:08:21.79 spid26s     Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1431].
14:08:21.80 spid26s     Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
14:08:21.80 spid26s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
```

This is my docker-compose file: (uncommenting the port 1434 line doesn't help)

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sql-data:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "MyDockerPwd!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "5433:1433"
#      - "5434:1434/udp"
    volumes:
      - sql-data-system:/var/opt/mssql
      - sql-data-user:/var/opt/sqlserver

volumes:
  sql-data-system:
    name: sql_data_system
  sql-data-user:
    name: sql_data_user
```

I have tried allocating both ports on this host:

```
netsh int ip show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
      5357        5357
      5433        5433     *
      5434        5434     *
      8884        8884
     49735       49834
     49835       49934
     50000       50059     *
     50060       50159
     50160       50259
     50260       50359
     50400       50499     *
     50508       50607
     51036       51135
     51259       51358
     61200       61299     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so disabling the host instance of SQL Server fixed this issue. I don't use it anyway.